# NGINX not routing calls from react app to backend app

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have an AWS Ubuntu server that hosts a react front end running at 127.0.0.1:4100 and makes api calls to a Go app using port 127.0.0.1:1323. I installed Nginx and setup proxy pass for these two ports in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` config file but I only get the front end getting called by Nginx. Using chrome inspect to check why the Go app is not serving some of the functionalities from the react app, I see this error

> client.js:772 GET http://127.0.0.1:1323/api/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED 
>   ERROR Error: Request has been terminated Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.

What am I doing wrong? Below is my default config file

```
server { 

listen 80 default_server; 
listen [::]:80 default_server; 

server_name _; 

location / { 

proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4100; 

} 

location /api { 

proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1323/; 

 } 
}
```

Comment: Is your react app pointing to http://127.0.0.1:1323/api/?

Comment: @ShawnC. correct I have the react app pointing to that.

Comment: The react app is running in the browser on your machine attempting to connect to a remote server using the IP of 127.0.0.1 which is an alias for your local machine. You need to change your React App to point to your AWS IP. `http://AWS_IP/`

Comment: @ShawnC. You rock...thanks so much.

Comment: @ShawnC. I had the same error and solved it by your advice. Thank you! but Here's a question. so Let's say the server name is mydomain.com. when a user visit the site through the domain, nginx shows the user http://127.0.0.1:4100 which is in the EC2 instance. From this case, I assumed that a user(client side) sends a request through mydomain.com/api and nginx sends a request to http://127.0.0.1:1323/ which is also in the EC2 instance but Apparently User needs to send a request to http://AWS_IP/? why can't nginx sends a request to http://127.0.0.1:1323/ ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your server is listening to port 80:

```
listen 80 default_server; 
listen [::]:80 default_server;
```

So, you should make your request to that port:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1/api/     => http://127.0.0.1:1323/
GET http://127.0.0.1:80/api/  => http://127.0.0.1:1323/
GET http://127.0.0.1/         => http://127.0.0.1:4100/
GET http://127.0.0.1:80/      => http://127.0.0.1:4100/
```

Then nginx should correctly proxy your requests.

### Update

To be more clear about nginx config.

```
server { 

listen 80 default_server;  // The port nginx is listening to ipv4
listen [::]:80 default_server; // The port nginx is listening to ipv6

server_name _; 

location / { // When you call this location...

proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4100; // You'll be redirected to this location

} 

location /api { // When you call this location...

proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1323/; // You'll be redirected to this location

 } 
}
```

Your configuration is okay [according to nginx docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/).

You said your client is trying to reach `http://127.0.0.1:1323/api/` but It should be requesting `http://127.0.0.1/api/` (whitout the port) to be redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:1323/`.

Here's another example:

```
server { 

    listen 80; 

    server_name localhost anywebsite.com; 

    location ~* ^/MyApp {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5130;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_send_timeout 2m;
        proxy_read_timeout 2m;
    }
}
```

In this case, everytime my url ends with `/MyApp` ex.: `http://anywebsite.com/api/MyApp` I'm being proxyed to `http://localhost:5130`. But if I try to access `http://localhost:5130` or `http://anywebsite.com:5130/api/MyApp`  I won't be able because nginx is listening to port 80 only. If you want to access another port you need to specify like this:

```
server {
    listen 80; 
    listen 5130; 

[...]
```

Comment: Not sure I follow. If you don't mind could you please edit the config file I have to reflect what you mean per above? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The configuration you sent seems to be fine according to [nginx docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/). What I'm saying is that you should call at port 80, not at the ports you want to redirect. 

What you need to do is change your client to call port 80.

Comment: My entry point via the aws dns takes me to the React app http://127.0.0.1:4100/ that is the port 80 nginx is listening to. The react app is the one that makes the backend calls and it is coded to make the backend api calls on http://127.0.0.1:1323/api. The client error you saw was because it is displaying what the react app is trying to call in the server, but nginx is not redirecting that call to the app that is running at that port. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, It does. But your entry point to nginx should be always 127.0.0.1:80. Proxy_pass will make nginx to get from Port 80 to 1323, not the other way around. React should be calling 127.0.0.1:80/api/ to find the back end application

Comment: Sweeeet that did it with a minor edit, since it is running on AWS I had to point to the AWS IP per @Shawn C. suggestionThanks.