# Angular API request to .NET 5 API - net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSE

Tags: .net, angular, ubuntu, nginx

### Intro

I am setting up an nginx server with angular universal as front-end and .NET 5 as a back-end API.

### Explanation

When trying to send a post request to the API i get an `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.
You can try it out yourself here: https://modernamedia.no/#kontakt

I have added console.logging for the error.

### Error

Error:

```
POST http://localhost:5000/API/Contact/Contact net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

```
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: 'error', …}
headers: ro {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:5000/API/Contact/Contact: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://localhost:5000/API/Contact/Contact"
```

#### Network inspection

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

Could this possibly be a CORS issue?

### Code

##### Angular - Contact service

```
export class ContactService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private toast: ToastService) {}
  private SendCTAMessageURL = environment.url + '/API/Contact/Contact';
  headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  public errorMessage;
  public SendContactRequestResult = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  SendContactRequest(model: any) {
    var request = this.http.post<any>(this.SendCTAMessageURL, model);
    var response;
    request.subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        this.toast.Toast(
          'Melding sendt!',
          'Vi kontakter deg snarest!',
          'default',
          5000
        );
        this.SendContactRequestResult.next(true);
        response = true;
      },
      error: (error) => {
        this.errorMessage = error.message;
        console.error('There was an error!', error);
        this.toast.Toast(
          'Det oppstod en feil!',
          'Kontakt oss på tlf: 902 65 326!',
          'error',
          10000
        );
        this.SendContactRequestResult.next(false);
        response = false;
      },
    });
    return response;
  }
```

##### .NET - Startup

```cs
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerManager logger)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "ModernaMediaDotNet v1"));
            }
            app.ConfigureExceptionHandler(logger);
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors(x => x
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
                    .AllowCredentials()); // allow credentials

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

##### .NET - Contact Controller

```cs
namespace ModernaMediaDotNet.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ContactController : ControllerBase
    {

        private ITwillioService twillioService;
        private readonly ILoggerManager logger;

        public ContactController(ITwillioService twillioService, ILoggerManager logger)
        {
            this.twillioService = twillioService;
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Contact(ContactModel model)
        {
            string body = $"Melding fra MODERNA MEDIA: \n" +
                $"navn: {model.name} \n" +
                $"epost: {model.email} \n" +
                $"telefon: {model.phone} \n" +
                $"bedrift: {model.business} \n" +
                $"tittel: {model.title} \n" +
                $"innhold: {model.body}";
            logger.LogInfo("Initializing message");
            logger.LogInfo(body);
            try
            {
            var result = twillioService.SendMessage(body);
                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                logger.LogError($"Something went wrong: {e}");
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {e}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could [this](https://could%20this%20be%20a%20solution?%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62157322/nginx-reverse-proxy-to-backend-gives-an-error-err-connection-refused) be a solution to your issue?

Comment: Partially, turned out to be a similar issue on my server. The front-end was unable to reach the back-end so I had to proxypass the API to an URL, works great now!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The issue with a lot of API calls is that a browser will tell you it is some kind of CORS error but there is an underlying error that has NOTHING to do with CORS.

However here I think you need to set your client headers to match the backend CORS setup: -

```
headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
```

try

```
headers = headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'localhost:5000',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, content-type'
        })
```

A second approach is to remove CORS temporarily from the backend to try and isolate the issue.

Also (unrelated but worth a look) your .NET controller is defined as: -

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
```

I find this a bit confusing, personally I would do it like this to give a little more clarity: -

```
namespace ModernaMediaDotNet.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")] // No action here
    [ApiController]
    public class ContactController : ControllerBase
    {
      ...
```

Then call

```
private SendCTAMessageURL = environment.url + '/API/Contact';
```

It will find the default POST method as it has no name parameter. You could then define it more sepcifically like this: -

```
        [HttpPost("Submit")]
        public IActionResult Contact(ContactModel model)
        {
          ...
```

then your url is: -

```
private SendCTAMessageURL = environment.url + '/API/Contact/Submit';
```

Comment: By the way .... nice looking form you have there! ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I added the changes you proposed and they're live on the server now. But the error still persists. Great information in your answer though and very nicely formatted answer. I could also point out that this works when I'm running the projects locally. I am thinking this maybe a server error.